# How to retrieve iCloud Documents Directory?

Tags: swift, icloud

I am trying to add iCloud sync to my app, but I am having trouble getting the directory of the iCloud documents directory so that I can move my files there.

I have added the iCloud capability to my app (though the app does not appear in iCloud Documents) and do have all the files saved to the local documents directory.

The local document directory can be loaded fine, but I am unable to load the iCloud directory using `FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: "")?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")`. How can I fix this so that I can return the url for iCloud to move my documents there?

Here is my code:

```
func reloadFiles() {
    do {
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "useiCloud") && CloudDataManager().isCloudEnabled() {
            files = try FileManager.default.subpathsOfDirectory(atPath: documentsDirectory)
            print("The local document directory = \(files)")
            tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            files = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: "")?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")
            print("The iCloud document directory = \(files)")
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Error: Files have not loaded \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using nil for the container identifier instead of the empty string. Does that make a difference?

Comment: It still gives an error: `Cannot assign value of type 'URL?' to type '[Any]'`

Comment: That `FileManger` method returns a `URL?`, but the `files` variable is probably an `[Any]` type.